# pass date dynamically to a query to calculate day wise results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I created a new topic as i am trying to divide my initial question into multiple pieces.

The initial topic can be found in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202047/day-wise-and-date-range-calculation).

I have created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ee295) link with table and sample data.

This is the Query that i have right now.

```
SELECT
  Order1,
  COUNT(UNit.UNIT) AS Units,
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(dd, INSV_DATE, '2015-01-21')) >= 31 THEN 31
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(dd, INSV_DATE, '2015-01-21')) < 0 THEN 0
    ELSE (DATEDIFF(dd, INSV_DATE, '2015-01-21'))
  END) AS Days31
FROM UNIT
WHERE Unit.INSV_DATE < '2015-01-21'
AND UNIT.MODEL IN ('Toyota')
AND (UNIT.Customer IN ('Jona'))
GROUP BY [Order1],
         customer
```

**how do i loop and pass date dynamically in the Datediff for a period of one month?**

I want the 31 days output calculated for day wise.

The output should be like

```
Date  |  Order1  |  Unit  |  Day31
----------------------------------
May20 |  90909   |  5     |  128
May19 |  90909   |  4     |  124 
May17 |  90909   |  2     |  62
```

I actually want to do something like the following.

```
SELECT
  Order1,
  COUNT(UNit.UNIT) AS Units,
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(dd, INSV_DATE, '2015-05-20')) >= 31 THEN 31
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(dd, INSV_DATE, '2015-05-20')) < 0 THEN 0
    ELSE (DATEDIFF(dd, INSV_DATE, '2015-05-20'))
  END) AS Days31
FROM UNIT
WHERE Unit.INSV_DATE < '2015-05-20'
AND UNIT.MODEL IN ('Toyota')
AND (UNIT.Customer IN ('Jona'))
GROUP BY [Order1],
         customer

SELECT
  Order1,
  COUNT(UNit.UNIT) AS Units,
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(dd, INSV_DATE, '2015-05-19')) >= 31 THEN 31
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(dd, INSV_DATE, '2015-05-19')) < 0 THEN 0
    ELSE (DATEDIFF(dd, INSV_DATE, '2015-05-19'))
  END) AS Days31
FROM UNIT
WHERE Unit.INSV_DATE < '2015-05-19'
AND UNIT.MODEL IN ('Toyota')
AND (UNIT.Customer IN ('Jona'))
GROUP BY [Order1],
         customer

SELECT
  Order1,
  COUNT(UNit.UNIT) AS Units,
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(dd, INSV_DATE, '2015-05-18')) >= 31 THEN 31
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(dd, INSV_DATE, '2015-05-18')) < 0 THEN 0
    ELSE (DATEDIFF(dd, INSV_DATE, '2015-05-18'))
  END) AS Days31
FROM UNIT
WHERE Unit.INSV_DATE < '2015-05-18'
AND UNIT.MODEL IN ('Toyota')
AND (UNIT.Customer IN ('Jona'))
GROUP BY [Order1],
         customer
```

**Running the same query for everyday with the different date.**

If you can guide me in making a day wise query that will be great.

Comment: Are you trying to get the sum of units "sold" each day and then display the total output for upto what day of the month you are in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the list of dates using a recursive CTE, then `CROSS JOIN` it against your table to get the list of days you want:

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = 'Jan 1, 2015'
DECLARE @EndDate   date = DATEADD(DAY, 30, @StartDate)

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT      @StartDate  AS ReportDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      DATEADD(DAY, 1, ReportDate)
    FROM        cte
    WHERE       ReportDate < @EndDate
)

SELECT Order1,COUNT(UNit.UNIT)  As Units,sum(CASE 
WHEN (datediff(dd,INSV_DATE,cte.ReportDate)) >= 31 THEN 31
WHEN (datediff(dd,INSV_DATE,cte.ReportDate)) < 0 THEN 0
ELSE (datediff(dd,INSV_DATE,cte.ReportDate))END) as Days31
FROM UNIT
CROSS JOIN cte
WHERE Unit.INSV_DATE < cte.ReportDate AND 
UNIT.MODEL in('Toyota') AND(UNIT.Customer in('Jona' )) 
group by [Order1],customer
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of what you want, here is my "guess":

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE = CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + '01/' + + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) -- cast as mm/dd/yyyy
DECLARE @endDate DATE = GETDATE() -- mm/dd/yyyy

--creates a list of dates for the running month 
;WITH month_dates
AS (
    SELECT [Date] = DATEADD(Day, Number, @startDate)
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values
    WHERE Type = 'P'
        AND DATEADD(day, Number, @startDate) <= @endDate
    )
SELECT month_dates.[Date]
    ,Order1
    ,COUNT(UNit.UNIT) AS Units
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN (datediff(dd, INSV_DATE, month_dates.[Date])) >= 31
                THEN 31
            WHEN (datediff(dd, INSV_DATE, month_dates.[Date])) < 0
                THEN 0
            ELSE (datediff(dd, INSV_DATE, month_dates.[Date]))
            END) AS Days31
FROM UNIT
CROSS JOIN month_dates              --cross join list of dates 
WHERE Unit.INSV_DATE < month_dates.[Date]
    AND UNIT.MODEL IN ('Toyota')
    AND (UNIT.Customer IN ('Jona'))
    AND UNIT.Order1 = 'A1056729'   --added this filter to test the output
GROUP BY month_dates.[Date]
    ,[Order1]
    ,customer
ORDER BY month_dates.[Date] desc
```